# How to avoid inserting row when the whole row is the same SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to avoid inserting duplicated rows when all the values are the same and the values are all variables, i'm using SQL Server with Python, the code down below:

```
import pypyodbc

def reg_db(cod, cv, cps, mktm, dataop, datafx, fee, atObj, qtd, pxc, pxcl, pxref, sales, kiko, strike, stkiko):

    with pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=x;UID=pebol;PWD=y;DATABASE=z") as conn:

        cursor = conn.cursor()
    
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO registros VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(cod, cv, cps, mktm, dataop, datafx, fee, atObj, qtd, pxc, pxcl, pxref, sales, kiko, strike, stkiko))
        cursor.commit()
```

Comment: use a stored procedure and let the database engine do the heavy work

Comment: Does your table not have a key? I would think that you would consider a duplicate as such long before you got to _every single column is the same_.

Comment: You can check using IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [ColumnName] FROM table Where....) if true then only add cursor.execute command of insert